# how to make a button to get a sequel number every time it's clicked (python)

Tags: python, mysql

```
def insert_data():        
    x=0
    x=x+1
    mem_id="00"+str(x)           
    insertname= textBox1.get("1.0",END)
    insertaddress= textBox2.get("1.0",END)      
    sql1="INSERT INTO customers(name,address,mem_id)  VALUES(%s,%s,%s)"
    val1=(insertname,insertaddress,mem_id)
    mycursor.execute(sql1, val1)
 
    db.commit()
    

button2 = tk.Button(root, text="  儲    存  ", bg="blue", fg='white', 
   relief="groove", font=('arial', 12, 'bold'),
   command=insert_data)
button2.place(x=160,y=220)
root.mainloop()
```

i want to make a button that every time i click it, it can generate mem_id to be like 001, and then the next time it can be 002... and so on...
but i don't get the result that i wanted. mem_id is always 001. i know something wrong with the part x=0 and x=x+1 but i don't know how to change it to get the result i want..
thank you for your helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to manage this from mysql by setting the mem_id field to auto increment.
Or you can make another query that returns the last number from your database and you add 1 before insert.